# Gauche correction in Bensen group increment

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I have difficulty understanding the use of gauche correction in Bensen group increment method to calculate the heat of formation. As an example, 4 times gauche correction (0.8 kcal / mol) is considered in the calculation in the hypothetical equilibrium between the following two isomers. How is that figure decided?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it.

1. Sight down each C-C bond along the backbone of the molecule and draw a Newman projection
2. Look at all 3 possible conformations in the Newman projection and pick the conformation with the fewest gauche interactions
3. Count the number of gauche interactions
4. Repeat with the next C-C bond along the backbone

Here is a drawing of the 3 Newman projections in 3,4-dimethylhexane that contain gauche interactions (there are no gauche interactions along the $\ce{C1-C2}$ or $\ce{C5-C6}$ bonds.  You can see that there are **4** gauche interactions in the molecule.

[image]